# Convert ByteArray to IntArray java

Tags: java

I have an `ByteArrayOutputStream` connected with a Dataline from an AudioSource. I need to convert the Stream in some significative values that probally are the sound values taken from source or not ? 
Well then how can I conver the byteArray (from `ByteArrayOutStream.getByteArray()`) in a intArray?. I googled it but with no luck .

**p.s.** the audioFormat that I used is : PCM_SIGNED 192.0Hz 16Bit big endian

Comment: what do you need the conversion from an byte array to an int array for?

Answer (score 7):

Use a `ByteBuffer`.  You can convert not only to different array types this way, but also deal with **endian** issues.

Answer (score 3):

You can try the following:

```
ByteBuffer.wrap(byteArray).asIntBuffer().array()
```

Comment: `UnsupportedOperationException`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11761700/unsupportedoperationexception-on-bytebuffer-aschararray-array

Answer (score 1):

When you do `ByteArrayOutStream.toByteArray()`, you get: `byte[]`. So now, I assume you need to convert byte[] to int.

You can do [this](http://snippets.dzone.com/posts/show/94):

```
/**
 * Convert the byte array to an int.
 *
 * @param b The byte array
 * @return The integer
 */
public static int byteArrayToInt(byte[] b) {
    return byteArrayToInt(b, 0);
}

/**
 * Convert the byte array to an int starting from the given offset.
 *
 * @param b The byte array
 * @param offset The array offset
 * @return The integer
 */
public static int byteArrayToInt(byte[] b, int offset) {
    int value = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        int shift = (4 - 1 - i) * 8;
        value += (b[i + offset] & 0x000000FF) << shift;
    }
    return value;
}
```

Comment: for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        int shift = (4 - 1 - i) * 8;
        value += (b[i + offset] & 0x000000FF) << shift;
    }
i dont understand this code ... i<4 means that 1 byte is maked by 4 bit ?

Comment: No an integer is 4 bytes so you just add one byte after the other at the correct position - although personally I wouldn't use an add to do that, that works fine too (minimally slower but if you don't call the function billion of times that's hardly important). Anyways use of a ByteBuffer should be preferred. Also note that doesn't take endianness into account.